# How to Protect Word (doc or docx) file from copy-editing

Tags: ms-word

Anyone know how with using programming to protect Word(doc or docx) file's from copy-editing with using macros or different methods of programming!?

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the document from modification. Afaik you can't block the selection and copy mechanism. And if it can be done, it likely can be also circumvented by anyone really interested in your text.

Doc/x are not created as read-only document. For that, you can try PDF, which has that feature (read-only and avoid copy-pasting), though also that can be circumvented, if there are people really interested in doing so.

Converting your pages into images and then embedding them in a new document can work, but it makes your file bigger (and OCR can anyway extract the text).

Comment: easily broken; very weak protection = unuseful: macros can be turned off (and they should be, for security reasons)

Comment: Mr. Shin, has you got any other methods to protect word file

Comment: the only one that comes to my mind is to convert each page into an image; that way, noone can copy-paste (but of course, they can extract text with an OCR software); password protecting the document may prevent changes, but copy pasting will be still possible

Answer (score 0):

If possible then you can build an application to open the doc/xls file within the application window and disable the control after wards in order to prevent user from copying etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft Information Rights Management (DRM) thing that may be able to do what you want it to do.

Take a look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/information-rights-management-in-office-2010-HA010354260.aspx and see if it will help.